# Javascript `this` in objects-in-objects?

Tags: javascript, object, this

Sorry for fuzzy post title, I can't formulate the correct name in English for this post.

For example I have such an object:

```
var APP = {
    a : 1,
    b : function(){
        return this.a;
    }
}
```

In such way, if I call `console.log ( APP.b() )` than `this` will be referring to APP and result will be `1`.

But how to connect to APP from sub-object?
Example:

```
var APP = {
    a : 1,
    b : function(){
        return this.a;
    },
    c : {
        c1: function(){
             return APP.a;
        }
    }
}

console.log ( APP.c.c1() ) // 1
```

This example works, but it's bad idea to point directly to APP. For example:

```
APP2 = APP;
APP = null;
console.log ( APP2.b() );  // 1
console.log ( APP2.c.c1() ); // APP is undefined
```

**UPD:**

I've got half-decision:
if I declare property `c` like a method:

```
c : function(){
    var self = this;
    return {
        c1: function(){
            return self.b();
        },
        c2: function(){}
    }
}
```

It will work, but I should call a method but not property (too much brackets) :

`console.log( APP2.c().c1() )` instead of `console.log( APP2.c.c1() )`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a factory method:

```
var APP = (function(){
   var self;
   return self = {
      a : 1,
      b : function(){
          return this.a; // could be self, only differs in non-context use
      },
      c : {
          c1: function(){
               return self.a;
          }
      }
   };
})();

APP2 = APP;
APP = null;
APP2.b();  // 1
APP2.c.c1(); // 1
```

Comment: @mykhal, there's no reason not to.

Comment: `var self = { ... }; return self` would be clearer, wouldn't?

Comment: @mykhal, If that's your personal taste, then go for it, I don't feel a need.

Comment: ok, from some point of view, the assignment is just a side-effect of an assignment expression :)

Comment: JSLint scolds on such structure ;) Version with `var self = {...}; return self` is clearer because in the end of function there are fewer brackets (less chances to make a syntax mistake)

Answer (score 2):

Two other ways of writing it:

```
function App() {
    var that = this;
    this.a = 1;
    this.b = function() {
        return this.a();
    };
    this.c = {
        c1: function() {
            return that.a;
        }
    }
}

function App2() {
    var app = {
        a : 1,
        b : function(){
            return this.a;
        },
        c : {
            c1: function(){
                alert(app.a);
            }
        }
    };
    return app;
}
```

Comment: i was slower (but independent), buy you have forgotten to mention, how to instantiate an app.. :)

Answer (score 1):

you can use more javascriptous way to do that:

```
var App = function() {
    var that = this;
    this.a = 1;
    this.b = function(){
        return this.a;
    };
    this.c = {
        c1: function(){
             return that.a;
        }
    }
}

var app1 = new App();

...
```