# javascript object this

Tags: javascript, function, object, reference, this

I have an object and it has another inner object. How can I call the parent object from the inner object?

```
var test = {
    init: function () {
        var instance = this;
    },
    call: function() {
        this.stop(); // works
    },
    stop: function() {
        this.parseText(); // works
    },
    parseText: {
        load: function ()
        {
            this.call(); //*** dont work
            instance.call(); // work, but what if i have this instance (same name) on another object, would'nt this conflict it?
        }
    }
};
```

I'm using an instance, which works fine, but what if I or someone wrote an instance (same name) var in another object, wouldn't it will conflict and overwrite this instance?

Comment: Your examples doesn't work. `instance` is only visible in the scope of `init`, and will not be usable inside `parseText.load`

Comment: like i told @Rob i wanted to use self/this or instance inside the object, rather then direct object name.. dont want to use object name inside functions, so how can i do that?

Comment: @Basit: Look again at Eric's answer, he's giving you a reasonable way to do what you say you want (a working version of your updated example, which doesn't work).

Comment: thanks guys, i found the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6873281/javascript-this-in-objects-in-objects

Comment: I realize that. That's what mine and @Rob's answers do. The point is that the way you've written the above code doesn't work.

Comment: @Basit: That's exactly the same as our answers! The only difference is we named our variables `object` and `obj` instead of `self`

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6873281/javascript-this-in-objects-in-objects

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If all you're worried about is `test` changing, do it like this:

```
var test = (function() {
    var object = {}
    object.call = function() {
        this.stop(); // works
    };
    object.stop = function() {
        this.parseText(); // apparently works, even though parseText is not a function
    };
    object.parseText = {
        load: function() {
            object.call(); // works
        }
    };
    return object;
})();
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, please check my question again, i have edited it. and no im not worried about it.. but i want to use $this or self or instance as a name, but im worried if someone wrote same var again and qould it overright or no?

Comment: @Basit: No, `object` can't be overwritten. It's a local variable to the anonymous function, so can only be modified within that function.

Answer (score 9):

[Eric's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7944335/javascript-object-this/7944353#7944353) gives you a reasonable example of how to do what you want to do, but doesn't really go into why.

In JavaScript, `this` is set entirely by *how a function is called* (*for now*; see below the fold for details), not *where the function is defined* as it is in some other languages that have the same keyword (Java, C++, C#, ...).

You, the coder, determine what `this` will be each time you call a function. There are two main ways: By calling the function via an object property (in the same expression), or explicitly using the function's built-in `call` and `apply` functions.

#### Via an object property

Using an object property:

```
obj.foo();    // or
obj["foo"](); // both work
```

That does two very distinct things, but which collaborate to set the `this` value: First, the function reference is found by looking up the `foo` property of the object `obj`. Then, the function is called. Because you called it as part of the same overall expression retrieving the property value, the JavaScript engine will set `this` to `obj` within the call.

So in your example, `test.parseText.load()`, within the `load` call  `this` will be `parseText`, not `test`, because that's the object on which `load` was looked up.

Note that setting-`this`-via-property-lookup only works when they're done at the same time. This does *not* work:

```
var f = obj.foo;
f(); // `this` will not be `obj` within the call
```

That doesn't work because they weren't done at the same time. The property lookup and function call were separated.

#### Using `call` or `apply`

The second way of setting `this` is more explicit: All functions have the `call` and `apply` properties, which are themselves function references that call the function using information you supply. In both cases, the first argument is the object to use as `this` during the call. So if we wanted to fix the example above that didn't work, we could do this:

```
var f = obj.foo;
f.call(obj);  // `this` will be `obj` within the call
f.apply(obj); // same
```

The only difference between `call` and `apply` is how you supply function arguments. With `call`, you supply them as further discrete arguments to the function; with `apply`, you pass in an array of arguments.

So these all do the same thing:

```
// 1 - Directly via property
obj.foo("a", "b", "c");

// 2 - Using `call`
f = obj.foo;
f.call(obj, "a", "b", "c");

// 3 - Using `apply`
f = obj.foo;
f.apply(obj, ["a", "b", "c"]); // Note the `[ ... ]`, one array with three elements
```

You can see how `call` and `apply` could work with your existing structure:

```
test.parseText.load.call(test.parseText);
```

That calls `test.parseText.load`, making `this` = `test.parseText` within the call.

What Eric did in his answer was to use a closure to make it simpler for you to call `parseText` with the `this` value you expect.

Further reading (disclosure: from my blog):

- [Mythical methods](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/mythical-methods.html)
- [You must remember `this`](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/04/you-must-remember-this.html)
- [Closures are not complicated](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/closures-are-not-complicated.html)

---

Up top I said:

> In JavaScript, `this` is set entirely by *how a function is called*
>   (***for now***...

The reason I said "for now" is that in ES6, JavaScript is getting "arrow functions" and unlike other functions, the value of `this` within an arrow function is set by *where they're created*, **not** how they're called: They get `this` from the context where you create them.

Suppose you were writing code in an object method and wanted to use another method of the object to, I don't know, output information from an array (yes, this is contrived). In ES5, you'd probably do this:

```
this.output("Entries:");
theArray.forEach(function(entry, index) {
    this.output(index + ": " + entry);
}, this);
// ^------- tells `forEach` what to use as `this` during the callback
```

If you left off the argument, you'd have a bug:

```
this.output("Entries:");
theArray.forEach(function(entry, index) {
    this.output(index + ": " + entry); // <== Bug, `this` is either
                                       // `undefined` (strict) or
                                       // the global object (loose)
});
```

But since arrow functions inherit `this` from where they're created rather than getting it based on how they're called, the arrow function version of that doesn't need the second argument:

```
this.output("Entries:");
theArray.forEach((entry, index) => {
  this.output(index + ": " + entry);
});
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6873281/javascript-this-in-objects-in-objects i think this is same in simple words

Comment: @Basit: You're right, and the accepted answer is largely the same as Eric's and Rob's.

Answer (score 5):

If you don't know the name of `test`, you can use a self-invoking anonymous function to create a wrapper, and refer to the object as shown below.

Note that `test` is not a reference to a function, but to the return value of the anonymous function. **Because the object name (`obj`) is wrapped inside a function, it cannot be read or modified from outside**

The solution below is neat, does not pollute the scope of `test`, and works like a charm. As mentioned earlier, `test` refers to the same object as `obj`. It's however not possible to manipulate variable `obj`, from outside, so that the code inside the function breaks.

```
var test = (function(){ //Self-executing function
    var obj = {
        call: function() {
            this.stop(); // works
        },
        stop: function() {
            this.parseText(); // works
        },
        parseText: {
            load: function ()
            {
                obj.call();  // obj refers to the main object
            }
        }
    };
    return obj; //Return the object, which is assigned to `test`.
})(); //Invoke function
```

### Update

It's not possible to reliably refer to `self`, `this`, or any reference to the object inside an object, without wrapping it.

Your current solution **does not work**, see comments in the code below:

```
var obj = {
   init: function(){
      var instance = this; //`instance` is declared using `var` inside a function
   },                       // This variable cannot read from "the outside"
   parseText: {
      load: function(){
          instance.call(); //Does NOT work! instance is not defined
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Looks like you put `return obj;` twice

Comment: @Eric Thanks, fixed. I started at the bottom of the function, moved to the top, and repeated the bottom by accident :p

Comment: @Basit See the boldfaced text in my answer.

Comment: i wanted to use self/this or instance inside the object, rather then direct object name..  dont want to use object name inside functions

Comment: @Basit: You need to study these answers (Rob's and @Eric's are largely the same) more closely, and probably read up on closures. Both answers offer reasonable ways to do what you said. Note that neither uses `test` within the function, they use a local variable inside an anonymous function which **cannot** be changed from outside that function, and so are safe to rely on.

Comment: @Basit See my updated answer. It's not possible to reliably achieve this without wrapping the code in a function. Wrapping the code in a function is the **best solution**. It's a maximum of 2 extra lines, while the readability of your code is maintained. Your other suggested methods are not transparent, and error-prone.

Answer (score -1):

"[call](http://vikasrao.wordpress.com/2011/06/09/javascripts-call-and-apply-methods/)" is actually a built-in function on the function object that can be used to call the function specifying what to use for this.  How does your code work?  It doesn't seem like it should since parseText isn't a function...

Maybe try this:

```
parseText: function() {
    var load =  function ()
    {
        this.call(); //*** should work
    };
    load.call(this);
}
```

Comment: this is just a demo, not real code. i wanted to clear my head on this, so i can implement on my large code

Comment: You turned `parseText` into a function instead of just an object.

Comment: parseText is called as a function in stop() isn't it?  I thought it was supposed to be.